# Difference between boost::asio::strand and boost::asio::io_context::strand

Tags: c++, boost, asio

I'd like to serialize http post requests using strand, to avoid overlapping writes to network.

My approach was to call the `post` method from the `strand` object with the callback that send the data as can be shown in the following code :

```
void Send(
   boost::beast::http::request<boost::beast::http::string_body> &req) {
  strand_.post([=]() {
      ...
      boost::beast::http::write(stream_, req);
      ...
  }
```

However, from looking at some examples, I've noticed 2 types of strand definitions :

```
boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand_;
```

```
boost::asio::io_context::strand strand_;
```

Any idea what's the different between each type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually not much difference between them. In fact, they share a lot of code and that shows that one was created from the other.

See diff [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/niif6Ud4) (bosst 1.67).

However, `boost::asio::strand` es a class template originally intended to be used with `asio::io_service`:

```
template <typename Executor>;
class strand
{
public:
  /// The type of the underlying executor.
  typedef Executor inner_executor_type;

  /// Default constructor.
  /**
   * This constructor is only valid if the underlying executor type is default
   * constructible.
   */
  strand()
    : executor_(),
      impl_(use_service<detail::strand_executor_service>(
            executor_.context()).create_implementation())
  {
  }
```

The class `boost::asio::io_context::strand` is not a class template and is bound to the class `boost::asio::io_context`:

```
class io_context::strand
{
public:
  /// Constructor.
  /**
   * Constructs the strand.
   *
   * @param io_context The io_context object that the strand will use to
   * dispatch handlers that are ready to be run.
   */
  explicit strand(boost::asio::io_context&amp; io_context)
    : service_(boost::asio::use_service&lt;
        boost::asio::detail::strand_service&gt;(io_context))
  {
    service_.construct(impl_);
  }
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help. However, I'm still confused which type to use for my need to serialize http writes. Perhaps you can elaborate on this ?

Comment: Considering that both are fairly similar, I would go with `boost::asio::io_context::strand` because it is explicitly designed for `boost::asio::io_context`.